# Why doesn't my loop iterate?

Tags: python, unit-testing, metaprogramming

Why does outer loop executes only last iteration?

```
class LanguageSpecificTest(unittest.TestCase):

    # Body omitted

for style in [  "inline", "inline_scripted",
                "external", "external_scripted",
                "internal", "internal_scripted",
            ]:
    print style

    for language, text_id, direction, text, check_text in (
                ("french", "reply_1", "с французского", "жизнь", "В большом дворце, в Ферраре, в один зимний вечер"),
            ):

        test_name = 'test_translation_test_phrases_for_%s_pages' % language
        def my_test_generator(language, text_id, check_text):
            def ubergenerator(self):
                #####
            return ubergenerator
        t = my_test_generator(language, text_id, check_text)
        t.__name__ = test_name
        setattr(LanguageSpecificTest, test_name, t)
```

And when I launch tests it prints:

```
inline
inline_scripted
external
external_scripted
internal
internal_scripted
http://127.0.0.1:5000/translate?lang=french&style=internal_scripted
```

and goes only through one test, not six. Why don't I see

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/translate?lang=french&style=inline
http://127.0.0.1:5000/translate?lang=french&style=inline_scripted
http://127.0.0.1:5000/translate?lang=french&style=external
http://127.0.0.1:5000/translate?lang=french&style=external_scripted
http://127.0.0.1:5000/translate?lang=french&style=internal
http://127.0.0.1:5000/translate?lang=french&style=internal_scripted
```

Oh god, save my Friday evening.

Comment: Why don't you show us something we could actually run?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with a debugger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    test_name = 'test_translation_test_phrases_for_%s_pages' % language
    setattr(LanguageSpecificTest, test_name, t)
```

You only use `language` in the `test_name`, so you overwrite the same attribute when you go to different `style`s.

Comment: You are right. Also I have to pass `style` as a parameter into `my_test_generator`.